# Не работает программа которая xor - ит 2 числа в 2-ичной системе

Tags: c++

Написал алгоритм для того, чтобы узнать и вывести xor двух двоичных чисел, и чтобы нулей в начале результата небыло. В первой строке вводяться разряды чисел, в остальных двух сами двоичные числа. Написал алгоритм, но он работает не полностью, проходит только четверть проверок. Сам проверял с многими данными, и он работает, так же учёл случай, когда n < m, но всёровно проверки не проходит. Сделать перевод в десятичную и делать ^ для двух десятичный и потом перевести результат в двоичную сисетму тоже не вариант, так ка количество символов в двоичной системе может быть 500. Где ошибка ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, m;
    char b;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int* mass1 = new int[n];
    int* mass2 = new int[m];
    int k = min(n, m);
    int* mass3 = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> b;
        if (b == '1') mass1[i] = 1;
        else mass1[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> b;
        if (b == '1') mass2[i] = 1;
        else mass2[i] = 0;
    }
    int f = 0;
    
    if (n > m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            mass3[i] = mass1[i + abs(n - m)] ^ mass2[i];
            if (mass3[i] == 0) f++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            mass3[i] = mass2[i + abs(n - m)] ^ mass1[i];
            if (mass3[i] == 0) f++;
        }
    }
    
    if (f == k) cout << 0;
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            if (mass3[i] == 1)
            {
                for (i; i < k; i++)
                {
                    cout << mass3[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может предоставите исходные данные и ожидаемые результаты?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что xor двух чисел дополняет меньшее из них ведущими нулями, а не обрезает большее под размер меньшего. Попробуйте вручную его посчитать для 31 и 6. 11111 ^ 110 = 11111 ^ 00110 = 11001 = 25, а не 1, как у вас

Comment: @EzikBro понял, спасибо

Comment: Вот это: `abs(n - m)` зачем? Вы в каком порядке вводите разряды чисел? сначала старшие или сначала младшие?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, зачем вообще n и m, если они вычисляются из строк... но попробуйте так:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int n, m;
    string a, b;
    cin >> n >> m >> a >> b;
    if (n < m) for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m-n; ++i) a = '0' + a;
    else if (n > m) for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n-m; ++i) b = '0' + b;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        a[i] = (a[i]-b[i]) ? '1' : '0';
    if (auto pos = a.find('1'); pos == a.npos) cout << "0\n";
    else cout << a.substr(pos) << endl;
}
```